# wordpress template specific metaboxes?

Tags: wordpress

i have built several diffrent templates for my WP site each calling diffrent metas.

ok, im looking for a way to add a meta-box that will only display if the correct page template is selected.

say i have a homepage.php template, this template calls some specific meta info that only the homepage uses, a call to action of example, so i need the meta-box to appear once the proper page template is selected and disappear if a different page template is selected.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: [You can find an answer to your question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27348256/1922144)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i finally found a way around it guys and here it is:

```
<?php
function my_admin() {
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
    $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
// check for a template type
    if ($template_file == 'home.php'){
        add_meta_box( 'product_info',
        'Informacion de Producto',
        'display_product_info_meta_box',
        'ex_producto', 'normal', 'high'
        );
    }  
}

function display_product_info_meta_box( $product_info ) {
    $product_price = floatval( get_post_meta( $product_info->ID, 'product_price', true           ) );
$product_code = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product_info->ID, 'product_code', true ) );
?>
<table>
    <tr style="width: 100%">
        <td >Precio Producto</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="80" name="product_info_product_price" value="<?php echo $product_price; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 100%">
        <td >Codigo de Producto</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="80" name="product_info_product_code" value="<?php echo $product_code; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin' );

?>
```

so... yeap i hope that dose someone out there some good :)

Answer (score 0):

[get_page_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template) will return the template you are looking at. You can switch on this to display the content you want.